# Select two column regions in R

Tags: r

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I can't work it out and googling isn't helping me.

If I want to find the max of each row within the boundaries I do this:

```
temp.df$S1max <- apply(S1[135:175], 1, max)
```

But how can I apply this to regions outside of that bounds? This doesn't work:

```
temp.df$S1mean <- apply(S1[0:135, 175:300], 1, mean)
```

Thanks

Comment: use `c` like so `apply(S1[c(0:135, 175:300)], 1, max)`.

Comment: or `apply(S1[-c(135:175)], 1, mean)` ;-)

Comment: @VincentBonhomme there is not going to be a better answer than yours. You should post it as such. :)

Comment: well @lmo's was not so bad either ;-)

Comment: @Daniel when you apply over a vector, consider using the the `sapply` function. :) `sapply(S1[135:175],max)`

Comment: @Therkel What's the benefit of sapply instead apply?

Comment: @Daniel I cannot explain it better than the top answer to the question [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/3560695).

Comment: haha, well that looks thorough and something that I need to work my way through. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative indexing:

```
apply(S1[-c(135:175)], 1, mean)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really easy!